# Black screen when installing Fedora 16

Tags: boot, system-installation, crash, fedora

I have read many other threads here and elsewhere but found no solution...

I'm trying to install Fedora 16 x86-64. At random points during installation I get black screens that do not go away.

I have tried adding `nomodeset` to the kernel options (by far the most common answer to this kind of problems) but it didn't help. I also tried it with combination of `xdriver=vesa`, still with no success. I also tried `acpi=off`, `noapic`, `nolapic` and `noapictimer` combined with and without `nomodeset` with no success.

Any suggestions?

Btw, my machine has an Intel i7-950 CPU, 12 GB RAM, Gigabyte X58A-UD3R motherboard, an ATI 5870 graphics card (Gigabyte GV-R587UD-1GD Bios F8) and a couple of SATA hard drives.

Comment: Can you access the machine when there is a black screeen from the network?

Comment: @Nils no I cannot: I'm installing Fedora and the crash happens before setup has even started to write to the HDD.

Answer (score 3):

Try `vga=normal` as kernel-parameter during boot.

Update: This helped me once on OpenSuSE: `noirqdebug`.
On that system the IRQ for the network device got disable because another device - using the same IRQ was not in use...

Perhaps your graphic adapter suffers the same fate.

Comment: @AlefSin I updated another possibility.

Answer (score 1):

I also had a similar problem while installing Fedora 17 on my Acer aspire laptop machine. The screen would always go black at the initial stage of install process. I found a temporal fix to this problem which enabled me to install it. Try adjusting display brightness before you start your installation. It worked for me. See http://joseblog.netau.net/tips-and-tricks/black-screen-while-installing-fedora-17.php

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that fedora is already installed and you can't boot it?

If so, try to boot in a safe mode(there should be an option in the grub menu) and see which errors occur. If there are no errors, try to run X-11 system by startx and see if there are some errors there. I had the same problem with the black screen and it turned out that the config file was wrong.

I've deleted the wrong line from the safe mode and then the system has booted.

Comment: No, I was trying to install it. The boot environment starts and I can go through the options for a few minutes before system suddenly crashes with a black screen. Still, thanks for the tips.

Comment: That sounds more like a hardware problem than a problem in the installer.